# FusionAuth Startup RejectedExecutionException

Tags: postgresql, fusionauth

I am trying to create an instance of FA on my VPS and have been running into issues. For some reason, the application throws this error when trying to start after maintenance mode tries to start. I am using PostgreSQL; the user has all the needed privileges; I can't find any meaningful error logs anywhere.
please help!

```
Feb 22, 2020 7:26:29.033 PM ERROR io.fusionauth.app.primeframework.error.ExceptionExceptionHandler - An unhandled exception was thrown
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@21acde7d rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@d93535b[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.submit(Executors.java:681)
        at com.inversoft.maintenance.action.MaintenanceModeDoneAction.get(MaintenanceModeDoneAction.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.util.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:414)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.execute(DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.java:79)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.perform(DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.java:62)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.validation.DefaultValidationWorkflow.perform(DefaultValidationWorkflow.java:47)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.security.DefaultSecurityWorkflow.perform(DefaultSecurityWorkflow.java:60)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultPostParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultPostParameterWorkflow.java:50)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.content.DefaultContentWorkflow.perform(DefaultContentWorkflow.java:52)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultParameterWorkflow.java:57)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultURIParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultURIParameterWorkflow.java:102)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.scope.DefaultScopeRetrievalWorkflow.perform(DefaultScopeRetrievalWorkflow.java:58)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.message.DefaultMessageWorkflow.perform(DefaultMessageWorkflow.java:45)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionMappingWorkflow.perform(DefaultActionMappingWorkflow.java:126)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.StaticResourceWorkflow.perform(StaticResourceWorkflow.java:97)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.RequestBodyWorkflow.perform(RequestBodyWorkflow.java:89)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.security.DefaultSavedRequestWorkflow.perform(DefaultSavedRequestWorkflow.java:57)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.DefaultMVCWorkflow.perform(DefaultMVCWorkflow.java:91)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.DefaultWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(DefaultWorkflowChain.java:44)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.servlet.FilterWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(FilterWorkflowChain.java:50)
        at org.primeframework.mvc.servlet.PrimeFilter.doFilter(PrimeFilter.java:84)
        at com.inversoft.maintenance.servlet.MaintenanceModePrimeFilter.doFilter(MaintenanceModePrimeFilter.java:59)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.inversoft.servlet.UTF8Filter.doFilter(UTF8Filter.java:27)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: It seems the executor pool has shutdown and is not accepting additional jobs. I assume there is more in the log than this exception, is the VM shutting down, are there other exceptions? What is the symptom you see in the UI, does the entire VM fail to start? I'd need to see the entire log.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had an outdated version of Java on my server. Just install the latest version using your package manager/installer (ex. yum, apt, etc.) and it should work!